# Android Use Google APIs as Library in Eclipse

Tags: android, build, project

I am working on android based application which includes few layouts with calls to web services using ksoap and displaying information on the screen. In a list view, I plan to display list of locations in ascending order of distance of location. On clicking the location in listview, application should be able to display driving directions from user's current location to selected location from list. Now to show the driving directions, I need to use Google APIs. For this purpose, I have to change my Project Build Target from Android 4.2.2 to Google APIs. Switching from Android 4.2.2 to Google API helps to start maps but with this change, my other application feature parts stop working. I read many questions online but could not find a similar issue someone  else faced..

Comment: Changing from android to google api, other feature parts can't stop working unless Google Api version is lower then Android 4.2.2 and you are using some feature included only in that new version. Give an example pls

Comment: @kinghomer, I was able to sort out the issue. Actually, after spending some good time, I was able to understand how to add google map using google play service's library project. Now it works fine. Thank you for your response !